# If $K \subseteq^{\mathrm{ess}} N \subseteq M$ implies $N/K$ is f.cog for all $N,K$ , then is $M/A$ f.cog for any $A \supseteq \mathrm{soc}(M)$?

Tags: modules

Let $R$ be a ring with unity and $M$ any unitary right $R$-module. We say that $M$ is **finitely cogenerated** if whenever $\lbrace A_\lambda \rbrace_{\lambda\in \Lambda}$ is a collection of submodules of $M$ with $\bigcap_{\lambda\in \Lambda} A_\lambda=0$ there exists a finite subset $\Lambda'\subset \Lambda$ such that $\bigcap_{\lambda\in \Lambda'} A_\lambda=0$. It's proven that a module is finitely cogenerated iff the intersection of any chain of nonzero submodules is nonzero.

For an essential submodule $B\subseteq M$, we write $B \subseteq^{\mathrm{ess}}M$.

Assume that whenever $K \subseteq^{\mathrm{ess}} N \subseteq M$ then $N/K$ is finitely cogenerated. How to prove that this implies that $M/A$ is finitely cogenerated for any submodule $A$ with $\mathrm{soc}(M) \subseteq A \subseteq M$, where $\mathrm{soc}(M)$ is the socle of $M$ which is the sum of all simple submodules (or, the intersection of all essential submodules).

I need any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You make $soc(A)\subseteq A\subseteq M$ sound like a restriction, but it is true for all submodules $A$... was this intended?  I wonder if you meant $soc(M)$ or something else.

Comment: I've voted to close for improvement because this is a poorly titled PSQ question.  Feel free to ping me if improvements are made and I can cast alternative votes then.

Comment: Oh! I edited the question. It was intended to be $soc(M)$ not $soc(A)$. Can you please now remove your vote for closing the question?!. @rschwieb

Comment: @HusseinEid. Thanks for fixing the statement! I would like to change the vote, but the post has not yet grown beyond a Problem Statement Question.  What are the dead ends you've encountered in your attempts?  Much like others i have a lot of desire to help you solve problems but I have little desire to do them entirely from scratch for you...

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't even know how to begin. I thought of taking a complement of $soc(M)$, say $K$, in $A$ so that $soc(M)\oplus K \subseteq^{ess} A$.

Comment: @HusseinEid What about supposing $M/A$ is not f.cog, then looking at $A\subseteq E(A)$, the injective hull?  $E(A)$ will be a summand in $M$, and $E(A)/A$ would be f.cog, and both could be useful.

Comment: @HusseinEid Can you also please improve the title of your question and transfer your comment work to the body of the question?

Comment: May you suggest please an appropriate title of the question?! @rschwieb

Comment: Use your question.  Like "Show that if $K\subseteq_eN\subseteq M$ implies $N/K$ is f.cog for all $N,K$, then $M/A$ is f.cog for any $A\supseteq soc(M)$."  You even have 24 characters leftover: you might be able to spell out "cogenerated"

Comment: Why $E(A)$ is a summand of $M$?!. Is it even a submodule of $M$?!. It is known that $E(A) \subseteq E(M)$ and hence $E(A)$ is a summand of $E(M)$. @rschwieb

Comment: @HusseinEid yes, you're right: might not even be a submodule. A slip on my part.

Comment: You might get more views if, say, you lifted a finger to use the title I typed out for you.